# flexibility reduces .. or flexibility reduce.., which one is correct?

Tags: grammar

I would like to say that the flexibility of the model is reduced as the 
dimension of the data increase.

> The flexibility of model A reduces as the dimension increases.

Is that correct or do I need to write it as follows:

> The flexibility of model A reduce as the dimension increase.

Could someone help me to understand which one is correct and why, please? As I learned, I need to have `s` with my verb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**A** is singular not plural therefore flexibility of model "**A**" which is the subject **REDUCES**.

If it were "flexibility of the model **A** and **B** reduces" it would've been wrong, because **A and B** are 2 things thus it should be **REDUCE**.

Only introduce an **S** to the verb when talking about a single object or person.

There shouldn't be an **S** when addressing more than 2 objects or 2 people.